# Android application Runs on emulator but forced close on mobile at the time of start of app

Tags: android-emulator

**Logfile of mobile given below.**

i am developing as android app, the problem is while development app runs on emulator but asks for force close in the mobile device. although i was able to install it successful in mobile. but when i run the app force close and unexpected error occurs. if there is any problem in the code then it should run in emulator also. but it is running on emulator.where did i commit mistake i am not able to get it.

```
W/InputManagerService( 1160): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2fc39418
W/ActivityManager( 1160): [CCILOG] set process: com.fourthmainhealth   restore=android.process.acore
E/msm7k.gralloc( 1160): [unregister] handle 0x448920 still locked (state=40000001)
D/FlurryAgent(11482): Event count incremented: Hlog: a1f75341-b61d-49e7-88f6-c98fe27e36e0
D/FlurryAgent(11482): Logged event: Hlog: a1f75341-b61d-49e7-88f6-c98fe27e36e0
I/Hlog    (11482): a1f75341-b61d-49e7-88f6-c98fe27e36e0
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd RSSI len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd dalggs101 network rssi -65 len = 26, 26
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LINKSPEED len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LinkSpeed 36 len = 12, 12
E/Database(11482): Failure 1 (near ",": syntax error) on 0x144490 when preparing '  INSERT INTO Badge (name, cumulativePoints, text, image) VALUES ('Qilin', , 'only qilins can control sugar for seven days straight!', 'badge_qilin');'.
D/FlurryAgent(11482): Event count incremented: Error creating tables and data: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error:     INSERT INTO Badge (name, cumulativePoints, text, image) VALUES ('Qilin', , 'only qilins can control sugar for seven days straight!', 'badge_qilin');
D/FlurryAgent(11482): Logged event: Error creating tables and data: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error:    INSERT INTO Badge (name, cumulativePoints, text, image) VALUES ('Qilin', , 'only qilins can control sugar for seven days straight!', 'badge_qilin');
E/Error creating tables and data(11482): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error:   INSERT INTO Badge (name, cumulativePoints, text, image) VALUES ('Qilin', , 'only qilins can control sugar for seven days straight!', 'badge_qilin');
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482): Couldn't open hlog.db for writing (will try read-only):
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error:     INSERT INTO Badge (name, cumulativePoints, text, image) VALUES ('Qilin', , 'only qilins can control sugar for seven days straight!', 'badge_qilin');
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1610)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at com.fourthmainhealth.db.HlogDatabase.execMultipleSQL(HlogDatabase.java:91)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at com.fourthmainhealth.db.HlogDatabase.onCreate(HlogDatabase.java:57)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at com.fourthmainhealth.db.HlogDatabase.getCurrentMilestone(HlogDatabase.java:488)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at com.fourthmainhealth.Home.getCurrentMilestone(Home.java:367)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at com.fourthmainhealth.Home.onCreate(Home.java:136)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4368)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11482):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/dalvikvm(11482): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aad2170)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(11482): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fourthmainhealth/com.fourthmainhealth.Home}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 68: /data/data/com.fourthmainhealth/databases/hlog.db
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4368)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 68: /data/data/com.fourthmainhealth/databases/hlog.db
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:170)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at com.fourthmainhealth.db.HlogDatabase.getCurrentMilestone(HlogDatabase.java:488)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at com.fourthmainhealth.Home.getCurrentMilestone(Home.java:367)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at com.fourthmainhealth.Home.onCreate(Home.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
E/AndroidRuntime(11482):    ... 11 more
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd RSSI len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd dalggs101 network rssi -68 len = 26, 26
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LINKSPEED len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LinkSpeed 36 len = 12, 12
W/Process (11482): ****** Before killing process, pid: 11482 ******
I/global  (11482): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
I/global  (11482): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
I/global  (11482): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
I/global  (11482): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
I/global  (11482): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
I/global  (11482): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
I/global  (11482): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
W/Process (11482): *** Process Name: com.fourthmainhealth   Pid: 11482 ***
W/Process (11482): Thread Name: HeapWorker      Tid: 11483
W/Process (11482): Thread Name: Signal Catcher      Tid: 11484
W/Process (11482): Thread Name: JDWP            Tid: 11485
W/Process (11482): Thread Name: Binder Thread #     Tid: 11486
W/Process (11482): Thread Name: Binder Thread #     Tid: 11487
W/Process (11482): Thread Name: Binder Thread #     Tid: 11488
W/Process (11482): Thread Name: FlurryAgent     Tid: 11489
D/Process (11482): *** Stack trace: ***
D/Process (11482): RuntimeInit.java(362): crash()
D/Process (11482): RuntimeInit.java(76): uncaughtException()
D/Process (11482): ThreadGroup.java(887): uncaughtException()
D/Process (11482): ThreadGroup.java(884): uncaughtException()
D/Process (11482): NativeStart.java(-2): main()
D/Process (11482): ~~~~~~ End stack trace.
I/ActivityManager( 1160): Process com.fourthmainhealth (pid 11482) has died.
I/UsageStats( 1160): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.fourthmainhealth
W/InputManagerService( 1160): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2fbcb398
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd RSSI len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd dalggs101 network rssi -65 len = 26, 26
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LINKSPEED len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LinkSpeed 36 len = 12, 12
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd RSSI len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd dalggs101 network rssi -66 len = 26, 26
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LINKSPEED len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LinkSpeed 36 len = 12, 12
I/ActivityManager( 1160): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.cooliris.media/.Gallery }
W/ActivityManager( 1160): [CCILOG] set process: com.cooliris.media   restore=android.process.acore
D/SensorManager(11295): found sensor: KXSD9 Tri-Axis Accelerometer, handle=1
D/SensorManager(11295): found sensor: MS-3C Magnetic Sensor, handle=2
D/SensorManager(11295): found sensor: MS-3C Orientation Sensor, handle=3
W/WindowManager( 1160): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
I/Gallery (11295): onCreate
W/WindowManager( 1160): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
I/CacheService(11295): Starting CacheService
I/CacheService(11295): Refreshing cache.
I/CacheService(11295): Starting CacheService
I/CacheService(11295): Refreshing cache.
D/DiskCache(11295): Wrote index with 1 records.
D/DiskCache(11295): Wrote index with 1 records.
I/CacheService(11295): Building albums.
I/CacheService(11295): Building albums.
D/DiskCache(11295): Wrote index with 3 records.
I/CacheService(11295): Done building albums.
I/CacheService(11295): Building items.
D/DiskCache(11295): Wrote index with 4 records.
I/CacheService(11295): Done building items.
I/RenderView(11295): First Draw
I/ActivityManager( 1160): Displayed activity com.cooliris.media/.Gallery: 1415 ms (total 12567 ms)
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd RSSI len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd dalggs101 network rssi -67 len = 26, 26
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LINKSPEED len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LinkSpeed 24 len = 12, 12
I/DORMANCY( 1247): usb plug in
I/DORMANCY( 1247): DormantEvt evt= 9
I/DORMANCY( 1247): Transit to State 4
D/WifiService( 1160): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED pluggedType: 2
I/NotificationService( 1160): action = android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
W/ActivityManager( 1160): [CCILOG] set process: android.process.acore   restore=com.cooliris.media
I/RenderView(11295): OnPause RenderView com.cooliris.media.RenderView@2fa958c8
W/SensorService( 1160): listener with binder android.os.BinderProxy@2f99b808, doesn't exist (sensor=KXSD9 Tri-Axis Accelerometer, id=1)
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11295): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
I/Gallery (11295): onDestroy
I/CacheService(11295): Starting CacheService
I/CacheService(11295): Built thumbnail and screennail for 1 in 2666
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd RSSI len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd dalggs101 network rssi -66 len = 26, 26
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LINKSPEED len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LinkSpeed 24 len = 12, 12
I/CacheService(11295): Preparing DiskCache for all thumbnails.
I/CacheService(11295): DiskCache ready for all thumbnails.
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd RSSI len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd dalggs101 network rssi -66 len = 26, 26
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LINKSPEED len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LinkSpeed 24 len = 12, 12
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd RSSI len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd dalggs101 network rssi -67 len = 26, 26
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LINKSPEED len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LinkSpeed 24 len = 12, 12
I/ActivityManager( 1160): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.fourthmainhealth/.Home }
W/ActivityManager( 1160): [CCILOG] Try to start a new process
W/ActivityManager( 1160): [CCILOG] Finish to start a new process
I/ActivityManager( 1160): Start proc com.fourthmainhealth for activity com.fourthmainhealth/.Home: pid=11516 uid=10055 gids={3003}
W/ActivityManager( 1160): [CCILOG] change app priority!  [com.fourthmainhealth]
I/ActivityManager( 1160): Process com.cooliris.media (pid 11295) has died.
I/ActivityManager( 1160): Process com.android.vending (pid 11310) has died.
I/WindowManager( 1160): WIN DEATH: Window{2fec91f8 com.android.vending/com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity paused=false}
I/WindowManager( 1160): WIN DEATH: Window{2f9f7060 com.android.vending/com.android.vending.SearchAssetListActivity paused=false}
D/GTalkService(28898): [GTalkService.1] logoutAllSessions
W/ActivityManager( 1160): [CCILOG] set process: com.fourthmainhealth   restore=android.process.acore
D/FlurryAgent(11516): Event count incremented: Hlog: a1f75341-b61d-49e7-88f6-c98fe27e36e0
D/FlurryAgent(11516): Logged event: Hlog: a1f75341-b61d-49e7-88f6-c98fe27e36e0
I/Hlog    (11516): a1f75341-b61d-49e7-88f6-c98fe27e36e0
E/Database(11516): Failure 1 (near ",": syntax error) on 0x137ab8 when preparing '  INSERT INTO Badge (name, cumulativePoints, text, image) VALUES ('Qilin', , 'only qilins can control sugar for seven days straight!', 'badge_qilin');'.
D/FlurryAgent(11516): Event count incremented: Error creating tables and data: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error:     INSERT INTO Badge (name, cumulativePoints, text, image) VALUES ('Qilin', , 'only qilins can control sugar for seven days straight!', 'badge_qilin');
D/FlurryAgent(11516): Logged event: Error creating tables and data: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error:    INSERT INTO Badge (name, cumulativePoints, text, image) VALUES ('Qilin', , 'only qilins can control sugar for seven days straight!', 'badge_qilin');
E/Error creating tables and data(11516): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error:   INSERT INTO Badge (name, cumulativePoints, text, image) VALUES ('Qilin', , 'only qilins can control sugar for seven days straight!', 'badge_qilin');
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516): Couldn't open hlog.db for writing (will try read-only):
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error:     INSERT INTO Badge (name, cumulativePoints, text, image) VALUES ('Qilin', , 'only qilins can control sugar for seven days straight!', 'badge_qilin');
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1610)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at com.fourthmainhealth.db.HlogDatabase.execMultipleSQL(HlogDatabase.java:91)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at com.fourthmainhealth.db.HlogDatabase.onCreate(HlogDatabase.java:57)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at com.fourthmainhealth.db.HlogDatabase.getCurrentMilestone(HlogDatabase.java:488)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at com.fourthmainhealth.Home.getCurrentMilestone(Home.java:367)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at com.fourthmainhealth.Home.onCreate(Home.java:136)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4368)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper(11516):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/dalvikvm(11516): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aad2170)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(11516): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fourthmainhealth/com.fourthmainhealth.Home}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 68: /data/data/com.fourthmainhealth/databases/hlog.db
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4368)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 68: /data/data/com.fourthmainhealth/databases/hlog.db
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:170)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at com.fourthmainhealth.db.HlogDatabase.getCurrentMilestone(HlogDatabase.java:488)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at com.fourthmainhealth.Home.getCurrentMilestone(Home.java:367)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at com.fourthmainhealth.Home.onCreate(Home.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    ... 11 more
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd RSSI len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd dalggs101 network rssi -66 len = 26, 26
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LINKSPEED len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LinkSpeed 24 len = 12, 12
W/Process (11516): ****** Before killing process, pid: 11516 ******
I/global  (11516): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
I/global  (11516): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
I/global  (11516): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
I/global  (11516): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
I/global  (11516): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
I/global  (11516): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
I/global  (11516): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
W/Process (11516): *** Process Name: com.fourthmainhealth   Pid: 11516 ***
W/Process (11516): Thread Name: HeapWorker      Tid: 11517
W/Process (11516): Thread Name: Signal Catcher      Tid: 11518
W/Process (11516): Thread Name: JDWP            Tid: 11519
W/Process (11516): Thread Name: Binder Thread #     Tid: 11520
W/Process (11516): Thread Name: Binder Thread #     Tid: 11521
W/Process (11516): Thread Name: Binder Thread #     Tid: 11522
W/Process (11516): Thread Name: FlurryAgent     Tid: 11523
D/Process (11516): *** Stack trace: ***
D/Process (11516): RuntimeInit.java(362): crash()
D/Process (11516): RuntimeInit.java(76): uncaughtException()
D/Process (11516): ThreadGroup.java(887): uncaughtException()
D/Process (11516): ThreadGroup.java(884): uncaughtException()
D/Process (11516): NativeStart.java(-2): main()
D/Process (11516): ~~~~~~ End stack trace.
I/ActivityManager( 1160): Process com.fourthmainhealth (pid 11516) has died.
I/UsageStats( 1160): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.fourthmainhealth
W/InputManagerService( 1160): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2f9c7330
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd RSSI len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd dalggs101 network rssi -66 len = 26, 26
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LINKSPEED len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LinkSpeed 24 len = 12, 12
W/WindowManager( 1160): window, consumed: KeyEvent{action=0 code=3 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=102 mFlags=8}
D/StatusBar( 1160): DISABLE_EXPAND: yes
W/WindowManager( 1160): window, consumed: KeyEvent{action=1 code=3 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=102 mFlags=8}
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd RSSI len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd dalggs101 network rssi -63 len = 26, 26
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LINKSPEED len = 4096
E/wpa_supplicant( 1231): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd LinkSpeed 24 len = 12, 12
I/ActivityManager( 1160): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10100000 cmp=org.jtb.alogcat/.LogActivity bnds=[0,295][320,359] }
W/ActivityManager( 1160): [CCILOG] set process: org.jtb.alogcat   restore=android.process.acore
V/alogcat (11423): started
I/alogcat (11423): new intent: android.intent.action.MAIN
D/alogcat (11423): stopping ...
D/alogcat (11423): canceling periodic saves
D/alogcat (11423): starting ...
V/alogcat (11423): resumed
```

Comment: do you have access to the sdcard

Comment: @shiraz : this crash isn't caused by an access violation.

Answer (score 0):

this is strange, your example should not even have run in the emulator (unless you had data available there that you do not have on the device.)

look at the error log, especially the line :

```
INSERT INTO Badge (name, cumulativePoints, text, image) VALUES ('Qilin', , 'only qilins can control sugar for seven days straight!', 'badge_qilin');
```

you are missing a VALUE parameter in this query...

Comment: addendum : you might be constructing your SQL parameters in an unsafe way if this is caused by the variable that is supposed to fill `cumulativePoints` is null...

Comment: If this is the error then it should not work on emulator also. but it is running on emulator

Comment: Are you building your sql parameters by hand, or are you using a third party library, or Android's sqlite management library?